# how to hide divs with a radio button

Tags: javascript

I wish I could show or hide a div following the selection of a radio button
I have 4 radio buttons
including 3 which must display the same div
and 1 another div
the best way i found is this one
But is there a way to avoid having 3 divs with the same content?
I would like to better explain myself that when we select "4 Cars, 3 Cars, 2 Cars" that the id = "liv-1" is simply visible, but that if "because 1" is selected that the id = "liv -1 "or hide

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.desc").hide();
  $("input[name$='choix_livraison']").click(function() {
    var test = $(this).val();
    $("div.desc").hide();
    $("#ref-" + test).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

2 Cars
<input type="radio" name="choix_livraison" class="choix_livraison" data-nom="POSTE-ENVELLOPPE-belgique" value="1" checked="checked"> 
3 Cars
<input type="radio" name="choix_livraison" class="choix_livraison" data-nom="mondial relay-belgiqueE" value="2">
3 Cars
<input type="radio" name="choix_livraison" class="choix_livraison" data-nom="mondial relay-FRANCE" value="3">
3 Cars
<input type="radio" name="choix_livraison" class="choix_livraison" data-nom="mondial relay-autre" value="4">

<div id="ref-1" class="desc">
  j'ai sélectionné 2
</div>
<div id="ref-2" class="desc">
  j'ai sélectionné 3
</div>
<div id="ref-3" class="desc">
  j'ai sélectionné 3
</div>
<div id="ref-4" class="desc">
  j'ai sélectionné 3
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Comment: Thank you mister jo for the answer and the explanation
I would like to better explain myself that when we select "4 Cars, 3 Cars, 2 Cars" that the id = "liv-1" is simply visible, but that if "because 1" is selected that the id = "liv -1 "or hide

Comment: it is still not clear. you must write in your question a correspondence table in what must be displayed or not according to the value of the selected radio button

Comment: thanks for the help
to be simple
if the first radio button is selected then
 the div id = "ref-1" is hidden, if the radio button number 2 or number 3 or number 4 is selected then the div is displayed
id = "ref-1" ... therefore no longer need the last 3 div in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of ids use data attribute to use the value you want. Like I assume you want to do it on language so I used `data-lang=""`. Tweak it to your liking.

ps. you also might want to do a default open one as a value is selected on loading the page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.desc").hide();
  $("input[name$='choix_livraison']").click(function() {
    var languageCode = $(this).data('lang');
    $("div.desc").hide();
    $("#ref-" + languageCode).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

2 Cars
<input type="radio" name="choix_livraison" class="choix_livraison" data-nom="POSTE-ENVELLOPPE-belgique" data-lang="be" value="1" checked="checked"> 
3 Cars
<input type="radio" name="choix_livraison" class="choix_livraison" data-nom="mondial relay-belgiqueE" data-lang="be" value="2">
3 Cars
<input type="radio" name="choix_livraison" class="choix_livraison" data-nom="mondial relay-FRANCE" data-lang="fr" value="3">
3 Cars
<input type="radio" name="choix_livraison" class="choix_livraison" data-nom="mondial relay-autre" data-lang="be" value="4">


<div id="ref-be" class="desc">
  languageCode BE
</div>
<div id="ref-fr" class="desc">
  languageCode FR
</div>
```

Comment: great a very big thank you it works perfectly too, you are great, thank you and thank you again

Answer (score 0):

this way:

1. use a form
2. use labels
3. use css
4. use the mdn doc -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle

```js
const
  myForm = document.querySelector('#my-form')
, divLiv = document.querySelectorAll('div.desc')
, ref_Divs = 
    { '1' : 'ref-2'
    , '2' : 'ref-3' 
    , '3' : 'ref-3' 
    , '4' : 'ref-3' 
    };
myForm.onsubmit = e => e.preventDefault() // disable form page reload
  ;
myForm.oninput = e =>
  {
  let ref = ref_Divs[myForm.choix_livraison.value ]
  divLiv.forEach(el =>
    {
    el.classList.toggle('selected', ref===el.id)
    })
  }
```

```css
.desc          { display: none; }
.desc.selected { display: block; }
label          { display: block; }
```

```html
  <form id="my-form">
    <label>
      2 Cars
      <input type="radio" name="choix_livraison" value="1" class="choix_livraison" data-nom="POSTE-ENVELLOPPE-belgique"  checked="checked"> 
      POSTE-ENVELLOPPE-belgique
    </label>
    <label>
      3 Cars
      <input type="radio" name="choix_livraison" value="2" class="choix_livraison" data-nom="mondial relay-belgiqueE" >
      mondial relay-belgiqueE 
    </label>
    <label>
      3 Cars
      <input type="radio" name="choix_livraison" value="3" class="choix_livraison" data-nom="mondial relay-FRANCE" > 
      mondial relay-FRANCE
    </label>
    <label>
      3 Cars
      <input type="radio" name="choix_livraison" value="4" class="choix_livraison" data-nom="mondial relay-autre" > 
      mondial relay-autre
    </label>
  </form>
  <br>
  <div id="ref-2" class="desc selected"> j'ai sélectionné 2 </div>
  <div id="ref-3" class="desc"> j'ai sélectionné 3 </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the code, but that's not what I'm looking for. I want when you click on value 2, value 3, value 4 that it hides a single div please and not a div by value

Comment: great a very big thank you it works perfectly, thank you and thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You have only two options. show a)  j'ai sélectionné 3 or b)  j'ai sélectionné 2. Then you can use a simple if condition in your event handler. Like that:

**workings example**

```js
const sel = document.querySelector('#sel');
sel.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const i = document.querySelector('input[name="choix_livraison"]:checked');  
  let val = e.target.value;
  console.log('=>',val)
  if (val == 1) {    
    // show output 1
    document.getElementById('output-2').classList.add('hide')
    document.getElementById('output-1').classList.remove('hide')
  } else {
    console.log(2)
    // show output 2
    document.getElementById('output-1').classList.add('hide');
    document.getElementById('output-2').classList.remove('hide');    
  }
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="sel">
  2 Cars
  <input type="radio" name="choix_livraison" class="choix_livraison" data-nom="POSTE-ENVELLOPPE-belgique" value="1" checked="checked"> 
  3 Cars
  <input type="radio" name="choix_livraison" class="choix_livraison" data-nom="mondial relay-belgiqueE" value="2">
  3 Cars
  <input type="radio" name="choix_livraison" class="choix_livraison" data-nom="mondial relay-FRANCE" value="3">
  3 Cars
  <input type="radio" name="choix_livraison" class="choix_livraison" data-nom="mondial relay-autre" value="4">
</div>

<div id="output-1" class="hide desc">
  j'ai sélectionné 2
</div>
<div id="output-2" class="hide desc">
  j'ai sélectionné 3
</div>
```

Comment: great a very big thank you it also works, it's great, thank you very much

Comment: @arthur thank you for your feedback. nice! if you like this  and the other answears, you can upvote them, too. Everybody would be happy  merci